# How do I prove that $x \equiv d \bmod(n\cdot m)$ iff $x \equiv d \bmod n$ and $x \equiv d \bmod m$?

Tags: number-theory

Does this statement hold for any number of factors in the first modulus?
One direction is trivial, but I'm stuck trying to prove the other.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Not as long as $d \equiv 0 \leq q \leq n$ for some integer $q$.  For instance, $x \equiv 3 \bmod 2$ and $x \equiv 3 \bmod 6$

Comment: Hint: Chinese Remainder Theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implication $x \equiv d \pmod{n}$ and $x \equiv d \pmod{m} \Rightarrow x \equiv d \pmod{nm}$ is false, which can be seen by taking $x = 4$, $n = 2$ and $m = 4$. But, if $\gcd(m,n) = 1$, the statement turns out to be true. Indeed, if $\gcd(m,n)=1$, then there exist $a,b \in \mathbb Z$ such that $am+bn=1$. If $x \equiv d \pmod{n}$ and $x \equiv d \pmod{m}$, then there exist $q_1,q_2 \in \mathbb Z$ such that $x-d = mq_1=nq_2$. Substituting, we get $x - d = (am+bn)mq_1=am^2q_1+mnbq_1$. Notice that $am^2q_1=amnq_2$, i.e. $mn \mid am^2q_1$, and, obviously, $mn \mid  mnbq_1$. This implies $mn \mid x-d$.

Answer (score 2):

This statement is right if n and m are coprime (or $gcd(n,m)=1$)

$(\Rightarrow)$ It is obvious.

$(\Leftarrow)$ Suppose that $x \equiv d \ mod \ n$ and $x \equiv d \ mod \ m$. There exist $a,b$ such that
$x=an+d$ and $x=bm+d$. Thus $an=bm$. Since $gcd(n,m)=1$, $a$ divides $m$. It means there exits $c$ such that $a=mc$. So $x=an+d=mnc+d$ or  $x \equiv d \  mod \ (n.m)$